# Banning user who is replied to (Discord JS)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

As title says, I'm trying to write some code that will ban a user if their message is replied to with the word ban. I think the way im getting the id of the original message is wrong but I'm not sure how to implement it otherwise. The error im getting is "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')"

```
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "ban" && message.type == 'REPLY') {
        const member = message.reference.author.id;
        message.guild.members.ban(member).then(console.log)
        .catch(console.error);
}
})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm suggest you do like this:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ "GUILDS",
 "GUILD_MESSAGES",
 "GUILD_MEMBERS" ] });

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.content == "ban" && message.reference) {
     const msg = await message.channel.messages.fetch(message.reference.messageId);//cache the message that replied to
     const member = msg.member//cache the author of replied to
     member.ban(member).then(console.log)//ban the user
     .catch(console.error);
 }
})
```

Comment: This ended up working, thanks.

Comment: Can u mark this post, if this post solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your current code to:

```
 const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ "GUILDS",
 "GUILD_MESSAGES",
 "GUILD_MEMBERS" ] });

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  if (message.content == "ban" && message.type == 'REPLY') {
     const member = message.author.id;
     message.guild.members.ban(member).then(console.log)
     .catch(console.error);
 }
})
```

To access the `Server Members Intent`:

1. Go to discord/developers
2. In **Applications**, click your project/bot
3. Click the **BOT** section
4. Scroll down until you see the **Privileged Gateway Intents**
5. Find for the **Server Members Intent**
6. Enable it

Now try the script again

[image: Server Members Intent]

Comment: This also does not work, now it gives me this error. DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at RequestHandler.execute
I'm assuming because this is the bot just trying to ban me now isn't it?

Comment: Does your bot have ban permission?

Comment: It has admin permissions.

Comment: Can I see your Intents?

Comment: const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES"
    ]
})

Comment: You missing one intents, check my edit answer

Comment: Now the error is "Error [DISALLOWED_INTENTS]: Privileged intent provided is not enabled or whitelisted."

Comment: @DerpyMustache I changed my answer, I hope this time it will work

Comment: @新Acesyyy , what your code does is banning yourself. Banning the author of the commands.

Comment: @IHZAQSTORM33 That's what the derpy wants